# Change attribute of specific nodes anywhere in xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, attributes

I need to change my xml file by setting the "id" attribute of some nodes to their position in the entire document.
Here's an example:

**My input XML file**

```
<root>
  <exampleParent>
    <exampleNode id="">
      <!--Some stuff-->
    </exampleNode>
    <exampleNode id="">
      <!--Some stuff-->
    </exampleNode>
  </exampleParent>
  <exampleParent>
    <exampleNode id="">
      <!--Some stuff-->
    </exampleNode>
  </exampleParent>
</root>
```

**Expected output**

```
<root>
  <exampleParent>
    <exampleNode id="exampleNode1">
      <!--Some stuff-->
    </exampleNode>
    <exampleNode id="exampleNode2">
      <!--Some stuff-->
    </exampleNode>
  </exampleParent>
  <exampleParent>
    <exampleNode id="exampleNode3">
      <!--Some stuff-->
    </exampleNode>
  </exampleParent>
</root>
```

My main difficulty is that the "exampleNode" are not all under the same parent, but are all over the document. 
I managed to change the "id" parameter of each "exampleNode", but I can only set it to a given value, and can't count through all of them.

**My XSL Code**

```
<xsl:variable name="prefixId" select="'exampleNode" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="setId">
    <xsl:param name="nb"/>

    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefixId, $nb)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="exampleNode/@id">
    <xsl:call-template name="setId">
        <xsl:with-param name="nb"><xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This code will generate a unique ID for each, but how can I change this to make this id reflect the ordre of appearence of the "exampleNode" in the document ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<xsl:number count="exampleNode" level="any"/>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="exampleNode/@id">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="local-name(..)"/><xsl:number count="exampleNode" level="any"/></xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdGZ